# When you establish multiple connections with Selenium, are all the connections active?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium's HTMLUnitDriver to login to a web server. My question is, if I launch multiple Driver's, will all the connections be connected simultaneously?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I get a connection, and I ask it for some information to conform that I am connected. On the FirefoxDriver, it shows up as a new process. On the HTMLDriver, it doesn't.

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail in your question.  It's not clear what you mean by "connected simultaneously," and you haven't told us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to see how many people can connect to my server simultaneously and execute a script I'm running on that server. So if I have 10 people, and they execute the script at the same time, will the server crash?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to using WebDriver with multiple connections to do load testing, but it's [not recommended](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/load-testing-selenium-vs-jmeter-vs-other-tools/3562#3562).

Answer (score 0):

If you launch multiple drivers (using Grid of course), there is one JSON connection that commands all the browsers that run on the remote node.  It isn't SSL and so you can use a packet tracer like Wireshark (or a proxy packet viewer app like Fiddler) if you want to sniff the line and see what kind of communication is going on between your Tests and a particular Grid node.